# Numpy .shuffle gives the same results each time

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random

I am attempting to take a pandas DataFrame, take out 1 column, shuffle the contents of that column, then place it back into the DataFrame and return it. This is the code used:

```
def randomize(self, data, column):
    '''Takes in a pandas database and randomizes the values in column.

    data is the pandas dataframe to be altered.
    column is the column in the dataframe to be randomized.

    returns the altered dataframe.
    '''
    df1 = data
    df1.drop(column, 1)
    newcol = list(data[column])
    np.random.shuffle(newcol)
    df1[column] = newcol
    return df1
```

It gives the same output every time I run it. Why is that?

Note: I am using the same dataframe every time.

Comment: Your `drop` doesn't seem to be doing anything, since you're not assigning the return value (of `DataFrame.drop()`) to anything and you're not specifying `inplace=True`.  Are you making a similar mistake by not assigning the return value of `randomize` back to your dataframe?  If you `print(df1)` prior to returning it, you should see it randomize correctly (provided `column` is valid).

Comment: I second what @jedwards says. Your first two lines should be combined to `df1 = data.drop(column, axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Your code***

```
def randomize(data, column):
    df1 = data.copy()
    newcol = list(data[column])
    np.random.shuffle(newcol)
    df1[column] = newcol
    return df1
```

***My `df`***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5), list('abcde'), list('ABCDE'))
```

***Your code + My `df`***

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
randomize(df, 'A')
```

[image]

And again

```
randomize(df, 'A')
```

[image]

Looks like it works!

Comment: copy/paste error? the first and second dataframe are the same.

Comment: @PaulH `loc[['c', 'd', 'e'], 'A']` are all different.

Comment: ahh yes -- i see it now

Comment: Interesting... perhaps I am entering some data incorrectly, where I am not taking the random set but something else. I will check and report.

Comment: When I save the results of two successive randomize(data, col) runs as r1 and r2, they equal one another, but simply running randomize(data, col) twice gives two different ones!

Comment: That is a different issue altogether.  I just copied your code and verified that it worked.  I'll update the post with a fix to that problem.

Comment: @NiklasBraun it's been fixed.  The problem was that all of your saved dataframes were pointing at the same data.  Your second one looked different then the first but also changed the first to be the same and now they look the same.  I altered the function to use and modify a copy.